# Where is Azure storage account connection string in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I try to upload a XML file to Azure FTP server, using this code:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-and-download-files-from-blob-storage-using-c-sharp/

I have difficulty to how find storageAccount_connectionString? I have access to the server in Azure portal but I cannot find this connection string.

```
//Copy the storage account connection string from Azure portal     
storageAccount_connectionString = "your Azure storage account connection string here";
```

Comment: It should be under access keys blade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **connection Strings** are found from Storage Account Access Keys Blade as already said by [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) **`(StorageAccount>>AccessKeys>>ShowKeys)`**.

If you are using a `Primary Access Key` then you can use the connection string in `Box 1` and if you are using `Secondary Access Key` then you can use the connection string in `Box 2`.

[image]

**You can refer the below Microsoft Documents for more information:**

[View and Manage Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-portal)

[Configure Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)

Comment: FYI this should be a link to the docs, as a comment. No need for an answer, as this is purely a documentation-based question. Also, over the past several years, this has been asked (and answered) in other question/answer pairs.